Vinculando a linha corrente do DataGridView WinForms a uma propriedade de item corrente do ViewModel
Desde o .NET 7, a Microsoft melhorou os recursos de vinculação (binding) do Windows Forms para aproximá-lo do WPF e de outras tecnologias XAML: Using Command Binding in Windows Forms apps to go Cross-Platform - .NET Blog
No WPF podemos vincular uma propriedade de item corrente do ViewModel diretamente a uma propriedade DataGrid.SelectdItem via XAML, mas parece que o DataGridView do Windows Forms não possui esse recurso:

DataGridView.SelectedRows espera uma coleção de linhas;
DataGridView.CurrentRow é somente leitura, portanto a vinculação falha;
DataGridView.CurrentCell é a maneira de definir a linha atual do grid, mas ele espera um objeto DataGridViewCell, e tentei usá-lo formatando o valor esperado (removi o código de verificação e deixei apenas o que importa aqui):

   var currentRowBinding = myDataGrid.DataBindings.Add("CurrentCell", 
                                                       mViewModel.Items,
                                                       nameof(mViewModel.CurrentItem),
                                                       true);
   // O evento Binding.Format é disparado quando o valor é alterado no DataSource
   // e precisa ser exibido no controle, mas precisa de formatação antes disso.
   currentRowBinding.Format += CurrentRowBinding_Format;
   // O evento Binding.Parse é disparado quanto o valor é alterado no controle e precisa
   // ser atualizado no DataSource, mas precisa ser analisado/transformado antes disso.
   currentRowBinding.Parse += CurrentRowBinding_Parse;

   private void CurrentRowBinding_Format(object? sender, ConvertEventArgs e)
   {
      var itemIndex = mViewModel.Items.IndexOf(mViewModel.CurrentItem);

      e.Value = myDataGrid[0, itemIndex];
      myDataGrid.Rows[itemIndex].Selected = true;
   }

   private void CurrentRowBinding_Parse(object? sender, ConvertEventArgs e)
   {
      e.Value = myDataGrid.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
   }

Fazendo dessa forma funciona, mas o programa começa a se comportar de maneira estranha. Parece que esses eventos são acionados várias vezes cada vez que a linha corrente do grid é alterada, e o programa fica lento e até algumas coisas param de funcionar, como botões que não fazem nada quando clicados.
Minha solução foi ouvir o evento BindingSource.CurrencyManager.CurrentChanged, para sincronizar minha propriedade ViewModel.CurrentItem com a linha atual selecionada no grid; e criar um evento CurrentItemChanged em meu ViewModel, para sincronizar quaisquer alterações feitas do ViewModel na propriedade ViewModel.CurrentItem com a linha atual no grid:
   private void CurrencyManager_CurrentChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      if (mCurrencyManager.Current != mViewModel.CurrentItem)
      {
         mViewModel.CurrentItem = mCurrencyManager.Current as TViewModel;
      }
   }

   private void ViewModel_CurrentItemChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      if (mViewModel.CurrentItem != mCurrencyManager.Current)
      {
         var itemIndex = mViewModel.Items.IndexOf(mViewModel.CurrentItem);
         mCurrencyManager.Position = itemIndex;
      }
   }

Existe uma solução melhor para este problema?
Em tempo, eu postei essa dúvida primeiro no SOEN (Binding a WinForms DataGridView selected row to an MVVM ViewModel selected item property) e um usuário sugeriu fazer um binding diretamente à propriedade Current do objeto BindingSource. Achei uma ótima ideia, mas, essa propriedade também é somente leitura e a classe BindingSource nem possui uma propriedade DataBindings para que eu possa criar essa vinculação.
